# python network sniffer for real time applications under load of 75K packets/second

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, tshark

I'm developing some application based on python (mainly due to flexibility to do changes) which shall listen to data on the Ethernet, save it to the database (sqlite) and display the data in real time. The data on the Ethernet is UDP based with some custom protocol on top of it.

My challenges:

1. I have already a Wireshark dissector which parses this custom protocol. However, I can't use it as tool like tshark (the application is MS windows based) is limited with how I can use it to stored data for real time application (the application shall be running for few hours). Each time I start the sniffing, a temporary file is created. If I'd like to have log rotate (so that the files will be in constant size), I can't use the display filter.
2. Using `scapy` - quick implement the custom protocol on top of the UDP. Now, I have made some test for data storing to sqlite and found some performance issues where it seems that not all the packets are processed by scapy i.e, I've took trace with Wireshark and with scapy and have seen that with scapy there are missing some packets. I've took a look on the statistics of packets per second and found that there may be **75K packets per second** on this interface as this is monitoring computer which see all the traffic in my network (from which I need less than 0.1% of the data).

2.a The monitoring computer can be in 2 network configuration: with ERSPAN protocol in between (i.e. IP protocol inside IP protocol, where my data is in the last part of the whole packet) or without it (due to which I can add some extra filter to the scapy's `sniff` command). Unfortunately, the 2nd configuration is not yet available.

Any suggestions what could be done on this?

Comment: You can probably craft a more advanced BPF filter that supports both network configurations. You can start filtering everything that isn't ERSPAN, hopefully this will make a rate that scapy can manage (I'd say max a few thousands pps)

Comment: @Cukic0d, can you please provide some example on what are you mean?